# Software to convert midi to sheet music

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I am a music student looking for software that can convert midi files to sheet music. Are there any programs for Ubuntu like the Windows programs Notation Musician or MidiNotate Player?

Answer (score 11):

Try [MuseScore](http://musescore.org). It's also in your package manager:

```
sudo apt install musescore
```

Or install it [via snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/musescore). Using terminal:

```
sudo snap install musescore
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the package `abcmidi` that provides the application `midi2abc`, capable of converting midi files to abc file.

```
sudo apt install abcmidi
midi2abc prelude.mid > prelude.abc  # midi to abc notation format
yaps prelude.abc  # abc format to postscript
evince prelude.ps  # open with evince
```

abc files can be easily converted to something printable with `yaps` from the package of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Rosegarden is mainly a full blown MIDI sequencer but it also comes with a quite professional [notation feature](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/tour/notation/) to convert MIDI data to scores:

[image: Install via the software center]

Depending on your needs in case you only need a small piece of MIDI to transform it to scores this may be overkill, but if you need to edit these files or start composing you may need one or the other of it's additional features.

Comment: excellent tool, easy to use and powerful features. however, the pdf export ("print preview") is very buggy for me, to the point of not being usable.

Answer (score 1):

TuxGuitar is similar to GuitarPro for Windows. You can import midis, edit sheet music, and export to ASCII, PDF, and others.

```
sudo apt install tuxguitar
```